# how to add a create react sub app in another main create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, single-page-application

I have to build an ERP module with different modules. Each module is an independent create react app. Each module will work individually like a course module and exam module. Now I want both in one create react app with links. for example. if a student has logged in he can access both the course module and examination module. whereas staff can access only course module... how to integrate it all.
pl suggest...

I have referred https://medium.com/@sumn2u/merging-different-isolated-react-apps-into-single-app-example-568db378870a but the submodules also have node modules and public folder in my case how to go further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request sounds like a perfect fit for micro-frontends. You write several apps, and each app is loaded on when url changes. This way you may want to have one create-react-app on /app1 url and another loaded on /app2.

See: https://single-spa.js.org/docs/starting-from-scratch.html

Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I exactly need something like this. but i could not able to follow.. can any one of you suggest any video or document to go step by step..

Comment: @Mary - did you try following the tutorial in the link provided? It is pretty simple and will show you how to set everything up.

Comment: thanks... I am following the page ... I will let you know the progress...

Comment: Link broken, try https://single-spa.js.org/docs/getting-started-overview